# Safari blank page from Umbraco-driven site

Tags: safari, umbraco

I am running a site using Umbraco 4.

In Safari (Mac) when I refresh the page I get a completely blank page; the page appears to have finished trying to load.

I'm using a lot of JavaScript so I tried to removing all JavaScript but the error still persists.

The site is here

http://www.dreamguts.com/

I would really appreciate any input.

Comment: Hi,

I have also noticed this behavior on the our.umbraco.org site. It doesn't effect all pages though. Which points to it being something specific to do with the type of page.

Does it effect all pages on your site?

T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some digging on this and it would appear to be a bug in Webkit:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26621

The bug report suggests that disabling the WebCore cache via Debug menu may help.

Tim

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for your answer, this hasn't worked however it seems to be a problem with the site and not safari

Comment: okay I have done some more digging I have found that this is nothing to do with java-script or css or image, I have found some old posts in safari forums of people complaining that pages aren't displaying has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: As I said - I've seen this behaviour on other sites and the bug report I've linked to says that it's a bug in Safari/Webkit relating to the cache handling.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I guess i was in denial that this is a browser issue and not my own error. thanks again

Comment: This is actually a bug in Safari, not WebKit. Already submitted a Bugreport to Apple, copy of it is at Open Radar: [rdar://19074069](http://openradar.appspot.com/19074069)